# Replace 0 only in mysql

Tags: mysql

So, im just trying to replace **ONLY** '0' in the table where has a column propertyDetailBedroom that is a string. The below is the example of data from the table.

```
Table 
1 | 0
2 | 10
3 | 10+1



select replace(propertyDetailBedroom,"0","Studio") from table
```

From the above code, it shows that i would like the whole list to be returned but only to replace the value **0** to be **Studio** without changing **10** or **10+1**.
This  query that i have would replace every 0 in the table. And that is not the expected result.

```
Table
1 | Studio
2 | 1Studio
3 | 1Studo+1
```

My expected result would still return all of the string but only to replace the only value that has **0**.

```
Table
1 | Studio
2 | 10
3 | 10+1
```

Comment: I'm not clear what you want , can you add desired output please.

Comment: Your current query is already generating the output you expect, so what is your question?

Comment: Are you asking for an `UPDATE` query?

Comment: What do the numbers and symbols in the second column mean?

Comment: hi guys, ive just updated the OP. sorry for not being too clear earlier. It would be a select

Comment: `WHERE propertyDetailBedroom = '0'` isn't enough?

Comment: This seems so simple, I'm left wondering whether the data set is really properly representative of the problem

Comment: @Strawberry Removed my comment.

Comment: @Strawberry That's why i removed my comment.

Comment: @Codelt. Fair enough.

Comment: @forpas would only return that one row of values? i would like the remaining of other types of propertyDetailBedroom

Comment: @Strawberry do u suggest another representation for the datatypes for 1+1, 2+1 and so on?

Comment: @lilsizzo this is why your answer is closed. You did not explain what you want.

Comment: @forpas yeah i hope i was able to explain better this time around. =|

Comment: I suggest only that you provide a more properly representative data set and corresponding result set. See: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: @lilsizzo: "Do you suggest another representation for the datatypes for 1+1, 2+1, and so on?" Are you open/able to change your structure? Because I think that would be your best bet, and can post an answer that would reflect a better data model, if you're open to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need `replace()`:

```
select 
  case propertyDetailBedroom
    when '0' then 'Studio' 
    else propertyDetailBedroom
  end 
from tablename
```

Comment: as simple as this is...kinda of newbie in this...this helps alot ...thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`CASE` is probably a better alternative, but here is another method using string operators

```
select 
trim(replace(concat(' ',propertyDetailBedroom,' '), ' 0 ', ' Studio ')) 
from your_table
```

Comment: ahh i like this alternative to manipulate data to fit an algo to solve another algo on the go...nice